# woocommerce checkout page redirection if user not logged in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to redirect woocommerce checkout page to my-account page when user is not logged in.

I have tried but it's not working

```html
<?php 
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    $checkouturl = home_url( '/checkout/' );
    if( is_page($checkouturl) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/my-account/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried? any code?

Comment: I have tried this code but it not works 

function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    $checkouturl = home_url( '/checkout/' );
    if( is_page($checkouturl) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/my-account/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

below is the code to redirect the users who doesn't loggedin on the woocommerce pages

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

put this code into your theme `functions.php` and it will work

Comment: When I clicked on my cart then it's redirecting to the login page. I know I am not logged in but it should display the cart page. If the user clicks to process to checkout then it should ask for the login.